# Scala Casbah MongoDB driver - Maven error

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

What is the correct way to set up Casbah MongoDB driver in Maven? I have the following error when I tried to run Maven build, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.mongodb:casbah_2.10:jar:2.5.1, com.novus:salat-core:jar:1.9.2: Failure to find org.mongodb:casbah_2.10:jar:2.5.1 in https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of oss-sonatype-releases has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

I have added the maven dependency as well and the repo location, but looking at the following URL from where Maven is supposed to fetch the jar file, it seems not to be there!

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/casbah_2.10/2.5.1/

What is the correct way to set this up. It is damn frustrating to have so many repositories without any jar files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The casbah main project has the pom file which describes all the dependencies.  As you can see here: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/casbah_2.10/2.5.1/casbah_2.10-2.5.1.pom

Typically, your build tool should be able to read the pom and fetch the dependencies.